# Largest submatrix that is an identity matrix

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to find the largest submatrix that is an identity matrix. I have no idea how to run through all the possible submatrices. I have however, managed to come up with a function that determines if a matrix is identity:

```
function isIdentityMatrix(matrix) {

  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
      if (matrix[i][j] !== 1 && i === j || matrix[i][j] && i !== j) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Any help in looping through all submatrices would be greatly appreciated. Keep in mind that I am a newbie to javascript.

Comment: Look for a `1` in the input matrix and try to grow the submatrix as much as possible until it is not identity anymore.

Comment: @Nico Schertler That should work, but it is a bit too advanced for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. This program

-Finds a sub-matrix
 -Returns true if that martrix is identity or not

**Note:** This works for nxn matrix only but can be easily tweaked to work with nxm matrix.

```
   let arr=[

[1,1,1,0,0],
[0,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,1]

];

let finalValue=0;
 let n=arr.length;

 let N=2;//size of submatrices

 function subMatrix(k,n,N,arr)
{


    let max_k_x=n-N+1;// per row max value of k
    let row=Math.floor(k/max_k_x);
    let col=k%max_k_x;


    /* 
      k=6,n=4,N=2
      max_k=(4-2+1)*(4-2+1)=9
      max_k_x=3
      row=2(starting from zero)
      col=0
    */

let matrix=new Array();

for(let i=row;i<row+N;i++){
  for(let j=col;j<col+N;j++){

    matrix.push(arr[i][j]);

  }
}

return matrix;
}

 function doSomethingWithMatrix(matrix,N){

for(let i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){

        if((matrix[i] && (i%(N+1)!==0))||(matrix[i]!==1 && (i%(N+1))===0)){

     return false;


    }

    }





 return true;
}

 for(let k=0;k<(n-N+1)*(n-N+1);k++){//k can vary from 0 to (((n-N+1)^2)-1)

     let matrix=new Array();
  matrix=subMatrix(k,n,N,arr);
 // console.log(doSomethingWithMatrix(matrix,N));
   //  console.log("   ");
if(doSomethingWithMatrix(matrix,N)){

        finalValue=N;
         N++;
         k=0;
         if(N===n){
             N--;
             break;
         }

     }
     if(k===(n-N+1)*(n-N+1)-1){
         N++;
     }
     matrix=[];

}
console.log("final N: "+finalValue);
```

You can change the value N inside the loop to check for NxN sub-matrices.